# zIndex doesn't change z order for circles with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Pardon my noobishness, but, although I've seen this issue discussed, I haven't found an answer. I am trying to draw concentric circles on a Google Map using the API v3, making each clickable as on a bullseye target, but always the largest one ends up on top, which means it is the only clickable one.

The following uses an array called "subjects" that consists of increasing radii and various fillcolors.

```
for (i=0;i<subjects.length;i++) {
 radi = subjects[i][0];
 fillcolr = subjects[i][1];
 zindx = subjects.length - i;
 newcircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        radius: radi, 
        center: centerPoint, 
        strokeWidth: 1,  
        fillOpacity: 1.0,
        fillColor: fillcolr,
        zIndex: zindx
    }); 
    // display it
    newcircle.setMap(map);
    // make outer circle clickable
    google.maps.event.addListener(newcircle, 'click', function() {
                circleClickedInfo(i);
         });
```

The circles are there, the zIndex is set, but the biggest circle is always on top. I have tried setting zIndex on a pass afterwards, boosting each zIndex by 10000, reversing the order in which I create the circles, not setting the zIndex explicitly, etc. I'm sure I am missing something obvious (see the aforementioned noobishness), but I can't figure out what it is. TIA for any pointers...

Comment: Not an answer, but I'm having the same issue. [Here](https://gist.github.com/791344)'s a full, minimal example (github gist) exhibiting the unexpected behavior, and [here's](http://sonzona.dyndns.org/zIndexTest.html) a live example. Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for every shape you need:

```
selectedShape.setOptions({zIndex:0});
```